# Convert text file data into table in R

Tags: r, text-files

I have data that has the form

```
sr:user1
target:user2
vt:4
time:12
sr:user3
target:user4
vt:42
time:120
```

Is there a simple way to make the data looks like the following by using R:

```
sr        target  vt  time
user1     user2    4   12
user3     user4    42  120
```

Comment: When you say has that form, is it a text file with those as lines?

Answer (score 3):

Assume your data is in the file data.csv

```
require(data.table)
f <- fread("data.csv", header=FALSE)
(x <- unstack(f, V2 ~ V1) )
```

Comment: The package name is `data.table`, otherwise an excellent answer. I checked to see if swapping the order of items affected the result, and it seems capable of maintaining the attribute-value associations better than the `scan` method I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This makes the assumption that your text file has a regular arrangement: `scan` can handle regular list input of multiple line data. Read the scan-help page section on the "what" argument for precise details.

```
inp <- scan(text= "sr:user1
 target:user2
 vt:4
 time:12
 sr:user3
 target:user4
 vt:42
 time:120", what=list(sr="",target="", vt="", time=""))
#Read 2 records
data.frame( lapply(inp, sub, patt=".*[:]", repl="") )
#---------------
     sr target vt time
1 user1  user2  4   12
2 user3  user4 42  120
```